# Netlogo procedure inputs: call by reference possible?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to pass an input to a netlogo procedure in a way that the value of the input can be modified from within the procedure? For example:

```
to test
  let value 200
  test2 value
  print value
end

to test2 [v]
  set v v + 1
end
```

If you run this, it will output 200. I would like to modify it in a way (without using global variables and without using reporter procedures) in order to have the output 201.

Comment: No, this is intentionally prohibited in the language design.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mutable object such as an array or a table.

```
extensions [table array]

to test
  let _a array:from-list n-values 10 [0]
  increment-aval _a 0
  print _a

  let _t table:make
  let _key "key1"
  table:put _t _key 0
  increment-tval _t _key
  print _t
end

to increment-aval [#a #i]
  let _old array:item #a #i
  array:set #a #i (1 + _old)
end

to increment-tval [#t #key]
  let _old table:get #t #key
  table:put #t #key (1 + _old)
end
```

Of course it is better not to use mutability if you do not need to.